# Weird site URLs

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

If I go to MathOverflow from another SE site by clicking on the link in “Your Communities” under the right-most menu on the top-bar, I do not end up with the usual `https://mathoverflow.net`, but with a strange URL such as

```
https://mathoverflow.net/?_gl=1*i2ckzl*_ga*MTc4NjgzMTAxMS4xNTQ3NjY2ODIx*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY2MzkzNzc4My41MC4xLjE2NjM5Mzk0MDAuMC4wLjA.
```

The string is different each time. The same happens when I go from MathOverflow to MathOverflow Meta or vice versa, but not when I go to any other SE site.

What is the meaning of this? Is it a bug?

EDIT: It’s not just MathOverflow. It also happens when I go from other sites to Server Fault or Ask Ubuntu, so it appears to affect all Stack Exchange sites with their own domain. Since it is not MO-specific, I reposted the report on [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382288/).

Comment: Can't reproduce this in my office (RHEL 8.5, Chromium). What browser do you use? Have you tried a different device/browser/incognito mode? Is Mercury in retrograde, have the goats bleated twice before the sacrifice? [Have you tried to blame caching?](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: This is Firefox 105.0 on Linux. Reloading the cache, restarting the browser, logging out and in, and trying private mode, made no difference. Now I checked that Chromium 105.0 does it, too.

Comment: So, as answered by VLAZ on Meta.SE, it turns out this is a Google Analytics cross-domain tracking parameter, and it goes away if you disable performance cookies.

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. I'm not used a browser without an ad block for years now.